# VS2022 Authentication fails when pushing code to github

Tags: github, push, visual-studio-2022

I am having the below error when pushing code to github

remote: No anonymous write access.fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/repo.git/'

Tried resolving by doing the following by doesnt resolve the issue

1. setting origin to https://personalAccessCode@github.com/username/repo.git
   --> prompt to login using browser login, code, token
   --> tried all and all didnt work
2. setting origin to https://username:personalAccessCode@github.com/username/repo.git
   --> prompt above error when push

Anyone have encounter this on VS 2022 community edition?

Answer (score 1):

Thank all for your help. I managed to successfully push code to git after removing a global settings that set the PAT access token which I use it to connect Azure DevOps

git config --global http.extraHeader

Comment: Great, well done! Did you had to *unset* (ie. remove) that `http.extraHeader`?

Comment: Yes, I have to unset it

Answer (score 0):

First, the URL should not include your token (you can include your GitHub user account name).

Second, VS2022 has an [integration with a Git credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72851780/6309): check if your is set to `GCM` (or `GCM Core`, even though [`GCM Core` has been replaced by `GCM`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309)).

Both GCM or GCM core are packages with the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), so make sure to use the latest one.

Below is the result I have got after changing URL and credential-helper as suggested. But still having the same error

[image]

[image]

Comment: After changing url to exclude token and account name and setting Git credential helper to GCM code. Retry pushing code up to remote and below the error I have. I was prompt to enter my personal token

Comment: @Xiaoxin Yes, it should prompt you to enter your token. And then it should store it, and not ask for it again.

Comment: Currently still having "Remote: No write access. fatal: Authentication failed for" error after keying the personal token

Comment: @Xiaoxin Can you check if the token is correctly registered with: `printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=yourLogin` | git credential-manager get` (replace `yourLogin` with your GitHub user account)

Comment: I got an error saying "Missing 'protocol' input argument" after running the above command

Comment: @Xiaoxin I missed a double quotes.  Let me try that again: `printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=yourLogin" | git credential-manager get`